# how to get data from mysql in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, retrieve-and-rank

Hello guys i am new on laravel and am currently working on laravel project i have got this project from someone all things are working perfectly but something i want to get from database and i dont know how can i do it i just want to get start_date and end_date from database before function please help me.Thanks.
    please see the situation
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFhhI.jpg

```
https://imgur.com/xWVvTm2

$categories = subscriptions::select('start_date', 'end_date')
                           ->where('business_id', '=', '$business_id')
                           ->get();
if($categories=="")
{
   $dbvalue['start_date'] = '';
   dd($dbvalue);
}
else{
   $gateways['start_date'] = '';
   dd($dbvalue);
}
```

Comment: and what is the problem? `$categories` is never going to be equal to `null`, it is always a Collection object ... if you are getting an error check your logs so you know what the error is

Comment: What do you mean of  (get from database before function)? before which function? more explain about your problem, please!

Comment: muhammad Hossein please check images link

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you wanna first record `->where('business_id', '=', '$business_id')`
use

```
$categories = subscriptions::select('start_date', 'end_date')
                       ->where('business_id', '=', '$business_id')
                       ->first();
```

and

```
$startDate=$categories->start_date
$endDate=$categories->end_date
```

but if you wanna get array use this

```
$categories = subscriptions::select('start_date', 'end_date')
                       ->where('business_id', '=', '$business_id')
                       ->get();
```

but you should sort this query then you can access to this data use foreach loop

```
foreach($categories as $cat){

}
```

Comment: i wanna first record ->where('business_id', '=', '$business_id') use but still same error

check out this images please

https://imgur.com/HC7v2Sp

https://imgur.com/N2WhDNA

Comment: Check logs.The logs are located in storage directory.

Comment: well what you think i paste your code in my project on right place or not

Comment: this error is showing in log

[2019-12-09 17:53:43] live.ERROR: Class 'Modules\Superadmin\Http\Controllers\subscriptions' not found {"userId":299,"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Class 'Modules\\Superadmin\\Http\\Controllers\\subscriptions' not found at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\UltimatePOS\\Modules\\Superadmin\\Http\\Controllers\\BaseController.php:18)

Comment: Sory my bad i looked on wrong image,your function _add_subscription don't have arg like $categories ,if you wanna get first record basic on arg in _add_subscription,you should use that code inside that function ```$categories = subscriptions::select('start_date', 'end_date')->where('business_id', '=', $business_id)->first();``` but change '$business_id' to $business_id if you wanna use quotation marks use " "

Comment: finally i got the solution with this code

        $data = \DB::table("subscriptions")
            ->select("subscriptions.*",
                    \DB::raw("(SELECT subscriptions.start_date FROM subscriptions
                            WHERE subscriptions.business_id = $business_id
                            
                          ) as date"))
                          ->orderBy('subscriptions.start_date', 'desc')
            ->get();
    dd($data);  

but still i want help of you that i dont get exact data that i want it's showing blank

image

https://imgur.com/eCrGeTW

Comment: Ok ,can you edit your post and put there result from dd($data) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59263194/i-got-the-blank-value-from-db-in-laravel-on-select