# I got the blank value from database in laravel on select

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

I am facing a problem that I want to get `start_date` from database, but I get only null values, it's not showing values.

Please check this image for better understanding: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cUPw.jpg

Here is the code:

```
$data = \DB::table("subscriptions")
    ->select("subscriptions.*",
    \DB::raw("(SELECT subscriptions.start_date FROM subscriptions
    WHERE subscriptions.business_id = $business_id
    ) as date"))
    ->orderBy('subscriptions.start_date', 'desc')
    ->get();

dd($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with the following code:

```
$datestart = \DB::table('subscriptions')->where('business_id', $business_id)->Orderby('id','desc')->value('start_date');
```

Thanks, Guys

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!

```
$data = DB::table("subscriptions")->where('business_id',$business_id)->orderBy('start_date', 'desc')->pluck('start_date')->first();
```

This will return you the last start_date.